# Magento thumnailimage - Magmi

Tags: php, magento, magmi

I would like to know the correct setting in Magmi needs to be set so that the magento "thumbnail" attribute is set to "small_image".
So that all the products on my site will use the "small_image" for thumbnails.

For example, using the "Default Values setter" and setting the thumbnail attribute to "small_image".

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this has nothing to do with MAGMI, you would set the images using the Images Attribute processor;

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

on import but to determine which one is used in the frontend you'd modify your theme's relevant template and pull the small_image rather than the thumbnail;

helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />